# Registrar con variable de salida usando ASP.Net y SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Estoy realizando un aplicativo en web con lenguaje **ASP.Net C#** pero estoy validando el `OUT` salida para que me muestre el mensaje de error:

Este es mi procedimiento:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE pAdminUsersEvaSmart @tipo INT
    ,@UserName VARCHAR(100)
    ,@ERROR VARCHAR(100) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @tipo = 0
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM seguridad..Usuario
                WHERE username = @UserName
                )
        BEGIN
            UPDATE seguridad..Usuario
            SET IntentosUltimoAcceso = 0
                ,IntentosActualAcceso = 0
                ,Conexion = 'DES'
            WHERE UserName = @UserName

            SET @ERROR = 'SE DESBLOQUEO CORRECTAMENTE..'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ERROR = 'NO SE PUEDE DESBLOQUEAR EL USUARIO NO EXISTE..'
        END
    END
END
```

Código ASP.Net:

```
protected void btnDesbloqueo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=10.0.101.85\\instbdd01;Database=Seguridad;User Id=sa;Password=SA123456789*;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("pAdminUsersEvaSmart", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipo", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ERROR", SqlDbType.Char, 500);

    cmd.Parameters["@tipo"].Value = 0;
    cmd.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = txtUserName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    conn.Open();
    cargardatos();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    Label1.Text = cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value.ToString(); ;

    if (Label1.Text == "SE DESBLOQUEO CORRECTAMENTE..")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "showmodalpopup1();", true);
    }
    else if (Label1.Text == "NO SE PUEDE DESBLOQUEAR EL USUARIO NO EXISTE..")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "showmodalpopup();", true);
    }
}
```

Como podrán observar sí tiene el mismo nombre por la cual debe ingresar a ese `if` pero no ingresa no entiendo por qué si son las mismas cadenas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: recomendación, cuando hagas esos errores, hazlos por códigos numéricos, es decir: código 123 = SE DESBLOQUEO CORRECTAMENTE.. y verificas en el IF por medio de números en vez de letras, tienes un mayor control :)

Comment: Cuando debugueas, ¿que valor tiene Label1.Text? Si ejecutas un exec al sp, ¿se realiza el update y la asignación del mensaje correctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De inicio, realizaría una pequeña reestructura a tu *Stored Procedure* para que no tengas un mensaje de salida:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE pAdminUsersEvaSmart @tipo INT
    ,@UserName VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @tipo = 0
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM seguridad..Usuario
                WHERE username = @UserName
                )
        BEGIN
            UPDATE seguridad..Usuario
            SET IntentosUltimoAcceso = 0
                ,IntentosActualAcceso = 0
                ,Conexion = 'DES'
            WHERE UserName = @UserName

            SELECT 'SE DESBLOQUEO CORRECTAMENTE..'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'NO SE PUEDE DESBLOQUEAR EL USUARIO NO EXISTE..'
        END
    END
END
```

Ahora, del lado de tu código C#, se obtiene el mensaje con `ExecuteScalar`, se valida el mensaje y se asigna al `Label1`:

```
string resultado = string.Empty;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=10.0.101.85\\instbdd01;Database=Seguridad;User Id=sa;Password=SA123456789*;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("pAdminUsersEvaSmart", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

cmd.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = txtUserName.Text;

conn.Open();
cargardatos();

resultado = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
conn.Close();

if(resultado == "SE DESBLOQUEO CORRECTAMENTE..")
{
    Label1.Text == "SE DESBLOQUEO CORRECTAMENTE..";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "showmodalpopup1();", true);
}
else
{
    Label1.Text == "NO SE PUEDE DESBLOQUEAR EL USUARIO NO EXISTE..";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "showmodalpopup();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si alcanzas a notar en la imagen que envías de la depuración, no se alcanza a visualizar donde se están cerrando las comillas para el valor de `Label1.Text`. Esto significa que SQL SERVER te esta mandando el texto con espacios en blanco a la derecha. Dicho esto

```
"SE DESBLOQUEO CORRECTAMENTE.." siempre va a ser diferente a "SE DESBLOQUEO CORRECTAMENTE..            "
```

Para corregir esto, simplemente cambia esta línea de código

```
Label1.Text = cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value.ToString(); ;
```

Por esta otra, que remueve los espacios en blanco del `string`

```
Label1.Text = cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value.ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre es Recomendable hacer estas comparaciones por Número o sea código de error en lugar de un string pero por lo que se ve en tu **LABEL1.Text** tu string no termina en el ".." aparentemente por lo que se ve continua con espacios al final es por esto que al comparar las cadenas no están coincidiendo.